# Access Raw Contact ID of a Facebook contact from the lookup URI

Tags: android, facebook, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

I know that it's not possible for Android applications to access Facebook contact info. What I'd like to do is just to retrieve the raw contact ID of a Facebook Raw Contact based on it's lookup URI. I don't need any other info from the contact.
I can obtain the lookup URI if the Facebook contact is linked to a GMail or Twitter contact. I'd like to use this lookup URI to retrieve the FB contact even if the contacts get unlinked.
Thanks